# codeigniter -URL Redirect with out controller in url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, url-routing

I will explain my question with an example

http://localhost/tutorial/tut/main_module/sub_title

say my controller name is tut and main_module and sub_title is two dynamic text only. My requirement is based on this sub_title i have to load content.

How i can hide controller name.
expected final url will be
http://localhost/tutorial/main_module/sub_title

Comment: you can use default controller to redirect all routes to that controller. `$route['default_controller'] = 'tut';`

Comment: see [this](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#reserved-routes)

Comment: but this is not my main page, its a sub page

Comment: `tut` is controller name. What is method name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use route rules for this. This should work for your exact example:

```
$route['main_module/sub_title'] = 'tut/main_module';
```

So for dynamic routes:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'tut/$1/$2';
```

Please note that this means any other route in your project will not work, as this is essentially a 'catch all' route. You will need to explicitly list all other routes with just two parameters

See [the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned main_module and sub_title are dynamic

Comment: See my edit, it now will route correctly for what you want

Comment: Your welcome! Please accept the answer too as it worked